# Call jQuery function by Angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to call a jQuery function only in a certain Angularjs controller/view?
For example, I want to call the slides function only in the home view.

Slides:

```
$('.slides').superslides();
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
     templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
     controller  : 'mainController'
 });

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

 }]);

 myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
   $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
   $location.hash(id);
   $anchorScroll();
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directive.

**JS:**

```
 myApp.directive( "superslides",
        function()
        {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {},
                link: function ( scope, element, attrs )
                {
                    $( element ).superslides();
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

**html:**

```
<ul superslides>
</ul>
```

Comment: without isolating the scope would be better